# How can I set another value in property listener?

Tags: scroll, javafx, listener

I want to speed-up my ScrollPane scrolling. I need something like:

```
scrollPane.vvalueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            scrollPane.setVvalue(oldValue.doubleValue() + (newValue.doubleValue() - oldValue.doubleValue()) * 2);
        });
```

but without stackowerflow exections and working..

May be there is a way to consume this like an event?

P.S. BTW, why does setOnScroll() fire only when scrolling reaches max (top) or min (bot) position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really recommend modifying a property while it is already changing, but if you want to do it you need to set a flag to suppress recursive calls. Here's an example:

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ModifyScrollSpeed extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(createContent());
        DoublingListener.register(scrollPane.vvalueProperty());

        Scene scene = new Scene(scrollPane, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    private static class DoublingListener implements ChangeListener<Number> {

        private boolean doubling ;

        private Property<Number> target ;

        private DoublingListener(Property<Number> target) {
            this.target = target ;
        }

        public static void register(Property<Number> target) {
            target.addListener(new DoublingListener(target));
        }

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            if (! doubling) {
                doubling = true ;
                target.setValue(oldValue.doubleValue() + 2 * (newValue.doubleValue() - oldValue.doubleValue()));
            }
            doubling = false ;
        }

    }

    private Node createContent() {
        TilePane tilePane = new TilePane();
        Random rng = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            Region region = new Region();
            region.setMinSize(40,  40);
            region.setPrefSize(40, 40);
            region.setMaxSize(40, 40);
            region.setStyle(String.format("-fx-background-color: #%02x%02x%02x;", 
                    rng.nextInt(256), rng.nextInt(256), rng.nextInt(256)));
            tilePane.getChildren().add(region);
        }
        return tilePane ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I don't actually see any other way to change the increment amounts for a scroll pane. Note that `ScrollBar` has API for changing the increment amounts via its [`unitIncrement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollBar.html#unitIncrementProperty) and [`blockIncrement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollBar.html#blockIncrementProperty) properties, however `ScrollPane` does not have equivalent properties.

There is a comment in the [source code for `ScrollPane`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.java) which says

```
/*
 * TODO The unit increment and block increment variables have been
 * removed from the public API. These are intended to be mapped to
 * the corresponding variables of the scrollbars. However, the problem
 * is that they are specified in terms of the logical corrdinate space
 * of the ScrollPane (that is, [hmin..hmax] by [vmin..vmax]. This is
 * incorrect. Scrolling is a user action and should properly be based
 * on how much of the content is visible, not on some abstract
 * coordinate space. At some later date we may add a finer-grained
 * API to allow applications to control this. Meanwhile, the skin should
 * set unit and block increments for the scroll bars to do something
 * reasonable based on the viewport size, e.g. the block increment
 * should scroll 90% of the pixel size of the viewport, and the unit
 * increment should scroll 10% of the pixel size of the viewport.
 */
```

The current [skin](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/ScrollPaneSkin.java) for the scroll pane hard codes the unit and block increments for its scroll bars (in the `updateHorizontalSB` and `updateVerticalSB` methods) in the manner described in this comment (i.e. 10% and 90% of the visible amount), so I see no real way to get at these. In Java 9 the skin class will become a public class, and so at a minimum you could subclass it and modify this behavior.

Comment: so in Java 9 I'll be able to simly increase mouse wheel scrolling speed? If so, im OK with it.

Comment: "Simply"? No. In Java 9 you'll be able to create a subclass of `ScrollPaneSkin` that implements the functionality that's missing, and install it in your `ScrollPane`. In a future release, they may provide that functionality, but as far as I'm aware, it's not scheduled for Java 9.

Comment: And now I begin to miss that times when I write in JS.. Thank you @James_D

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this -

```
private boolean scrolllChanging = false; 

private void myScroll(ObservableDoubleValue observable, Double oldValue, Double newValue) {
    if (!scrollChanging) {
        try {
            scrollChanging = true; 
            // Insert logic here. Any subsequent changes won't reach here until `scrollChanging` is set to false again. 
        } finally {
            scrollChanging = false; 
        }
    }
}

scrollPane.vvalueProperty().addListener(this::myScroll);
```

Forgive any minor type errors, I have not compiled this.